# Configuring multiple data sources in spring-web.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Multiple data sources in spring

My spring-web.xml is like this

```
<!-- Data source Bean -->
<bean id="dataSource"
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:as400://localhost/BB" />
    <property name="username" value="ROOT" />
    <property name="password" value="ROOT" />
</bean>
```

My DAOImpl is like this

```
public class BBDAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements BBDao {    

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public List<Map<String, Object>> getDetails(String customerId) {
    String sql = "<SQL Query>";
    if(BBUtil.getInstance().isNotEmpty(customerId)) {
        try {
            return getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql,customerId);
        }  catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            logger.error("Empty result data - getDetails");
        }
    } else {
        // Want to configure here from second data source
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here getJdbcTemplate() method is pointing directly to the AS400 DB(But how). Now, my another requirement has come up. In the else block I want to do some data manipulation from another SQL Server.

Can any one tell me how to configure multiple DB's in this and how to use them?

This project is already developed using XML configuration and now I cannot go back to annotations config.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

Define two sets of jdbc templates like below:

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"/>
</bean>
```

then ahead inject them in repository like below:

```
    @Resource("jdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Resource("jdbcTemplate2")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2;
```

Define two data sources in your spring data configuration file like below:

```
<!-- Data source Bean 1 -->
 <bean id="dataSource"
 class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

   <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" />
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:as400://localhost/BB" />
   <property name="username" value="ROOT" />
   <property name="password" value="ROOT" />
</bean>
```

```
<bean id="dataSource2"
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:as4002://localhost/BB2" />
    <property name="username" value="ROOT" />
    <property name="password" value="ROOT" />
</bean>
```

and then inject those data sources like below in your repository class and use wherever you want to :

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource1;
```

Now use 2nd JDBC template for your if else requirement it will use datasource 2.

Comment: How come getJdbcTemplate() will understand which data source to use?

Comment: Answer Updated to add jdbc template explanation . Please have look.

Comment: It is accepting only  @Resource but not  @Resource("jdbcTemplate"). Please check syntax

Comment: only resource also do

Answer (score 1):

You can configure an additional data source like

```
<bean id="dataSource1"
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:as400://localhost/BB" />
    <property name="username" value="ROOT" />
    <property name="password" value="ROOT" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource2"
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:as400://localhost/BB" />
    <property name="username" value="ROOT" />
    <property name="password" value="ROOT" />
</bean>
```

And then while you want to inject, you can use `@Qualifier` annotation.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource1")
DataSource dataSource1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource2")
DataSource dataSource2;
```

Now, whenever in a class you want to use first datasource, you will use variable `dataSource1`, and when you want to use second datasource, you will have to use variable `dataSource2`.

However, now you will have to modifiy all the data access layers with `@Qualifier` annotation, because Spring's will have two datasource candidates to inject to in Datasource, And it is likely to ask you which one to inject.

Comment: How come getJdbcTemplate() will understand which data source to use?

Comment: Updated answer. Please check.